# valid 0 and 1 String recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I want to write a recursive algorithm that evaluates a string of ones and zeros and determines if the string is valid. The string is invalid if the string contains 3 zeroes in a row.

For example :

1010010001 invalid

1111101101 valid

1000111101 invalid

I have no idea how to write this algorithm. Thank you for any help.

Comment: So what's stopping you? Which language you are trying? What have you tried yet?

Comment: @SMA : I just want to write its algorithm .

Comment: Why recursive? Recursion is not needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this ( assuming **str** is your string and **n** is its length and indexing is 0 based )

```
           func ( index )
               if index >= n
                  return true 
               if index < 2
                  return func(index+1)
               if str[index] is 0 and str[index-1] is 0 and str[index-2] is 0
                  return false
               return func(index+1)

             // call func(0) , assuming str is global , also answer is boolean
             answer = func(0)
```

Time complexity is **O(n)**. Just for completeness for such a strightforward
thing I would just write it iteratively using a loop.

```
        //This is in c/c++
        bool answer = true;
        for(i = 2;i < n;i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == '0' && str[i-1] == '0' && str[i-2] == '0')
                  answer = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isValid(String s){
        return isValidInt(s)==3;
    }

    private static int isValidInt(String s){
        if( s == null || s.length() ==0)
                return 0;
        int prevSum=isValidInt(s.substring(1));
        if( prevSum == 3 )
            return 3;
        return s.charAt(0) != '0' ?0:1+prevSum;
    }
```